# What difference does it make to subscribe to a normal type and a observable type in here?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

```
  let s = "Hello World"
  let string = BehaviorSubject(value: s)

  //Example 1
  string
    .map { _ in "hhh" }
    .subscribe(onNext: { element in
      print(element)
    }, onCompleted: {
      print("completed")
    }
  )

  //Example 2
  string
    .flatMap { s -> Observable<String> in
      Observable.just("lll")
    }
    .subscribe(onNext: { element in
      print(element)
    }, onCompleted: {
      print("completed")
    }
  )

  //Example 3
  let aaa = string
    .map { _ in "hhh" }

  //Example 4    
  let bbb = string
    .flatMap { s -> Observable<String> in
      Observable.just("lll")
  }
```

I'm pretty new to RX world, in example 1 & 2, I use `map` and `flatMap` to test to test out this behaviour. one of the major difference between them is  `map` return normal value type whereas the `flatMap` returns Observable type.

In example 3 & 4, it shows that the type of both `aaa` and `bbb` are `Observable<String>`..

Now, since at the end they become the same thing, why do you even need `flatMap` to return a specific `Observable` type? or why do you need `map` to return a `normal value` type?

(I know that `flatMap` can do other things, it's not part of this confusion)

Comment: So the question is "what's the difference between `map` and `flatMap`"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map` operator is used to transform the value and pass the transformed value to next operator where as `flatmap` flattens the hierarchy of observables and exposes it as single operator

**Use case for `map` and `flatmap`**

In general you use `map` if you wanna transform the value you have received in your current operator and pass it on to next operator usually synchronously. Example in your case no matter what value is assigned to `BehaviorRelay` `String` you wanna return "hhh" which is straight forward synchronous value transformation so `map` makes sense

```
string
    .map { _ in "hhh" }
    .subscribe(onNext: { element in
      print(element)
    }, onCompleted: {
      print("completed")
    }
  )
```

`flatmap` is used to flatten the hierarchy of observables and expose it to next operator simply as a single observable. Example assume you are implementing search, once the value is triggered, you wanna make API call and pass the response to next operator. Now making API call is a asynchronous operation and you know that simple `map` will not cut through then you might use `flatmap`

```
let string = BehaviorRelay<String>(value: "abcd")
    string
        .flatMap { s -> Observable<Response> in
            return Observable<Response>.create({ (observer) -> Disposable in
                //make api call here
                //pass data / error using observer.onNext or observer.onError()
                return Disposables.create()
            })
        }
        .subscribe(onNext: { element in
            print(element)
        }, onCompleted: {
            print("completed")
        }
    )
```

So here actual API call is made by observable inside the `flatMap` operator but for outer world it looks like BehaviorRelay itself transformed the value of type string to Response.

Which is perfect because one need not know the nitty-gritty involved in making API call :)

But to be really honest, if you are really implementing search you would rather choose `flatMapLatest` rather than `flatmap`. Read more on `flatMap` and `flatMapLatest` for better understanding :)

Comment: Thanks! so would I say that another major difference between `map` and `flatMap` is sync vs async? is that correct?

Comment: @tony-lin : Not really, I just explained the use case when u might opt for `map` and `flatmap` as you did you used observable to do the sync value transformation which works fine as well :) but will that be a good use case to use 'faltmap` no is what I was pointing out, real difference is map transforms value where as `flatmap` flattens the hierarchy of observables :)

Comment: @tony-lin : Updated my answer for clarifying the doubt

Answer (score 2):

They are different in a couple of ways.

- `map` only emits one value for each value that comes into it. Whereas `flatMap` can emit one *or more* values for each value that comes into it.
- The closure passed to map needs to be "pure" (no side effects) whereas the closure passed to `flatMap` can have side effects (for example disk access, UI access and network access.) Yes, because Swift is an impure language, you *could* put side effects inside `map` but doing so breaks the contract.

Sandeep's answer gave an example of the second point, below is an example of the first point:

```
let string = Observable.of("a", "b", "c")

//Example 1
string
    .map { "\($0)-x" }
    .subscribe(onNext: { element in
        print(element) // only prints three values
    }, onCompleted: {
        print("completed")
    }
)

//Example 2
string
    .flatMap { Observable.of("\($0)-x", "\($0)-y", "\($0)-z") }
    .subscribe(onNext: { element in
        print(element) // this prints 9 values.
    }, onCompleted: {
        print("completed")
    }
)
```